# Why the sender is not approved? (v0.8)

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have the following code:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Collectioning is ERC721 {
...
address ownerAddress = ownerOf(_tokenId);
address payable pSender = payable(msg.sender);
transferFrom(ownerAddress, pSender, _tokenId);
address payable ownerAddressPayable = _make_payable(ownerAddress);
ownerAddressPayable.transfer(itemCost);
if(msg.value > starCost) {
  pSender.transfer(msg.value - itemCost);
}
```

`transferFrom` includes also the approval by the owner, but I keep getting this:

`ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved.`

I cannot debug to the console (don't know how), so the only clue I have is that the error comes from somwewhere in this block of code, triggered buy one of the transfers.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/0d40f705a7d4a42ff622ae3a0e1a90305fc5b93e/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L153

The error means that you can't issue `transferFrom` from an account which hasn't approved the transfer (or you're not the owner). Whenever you use `transferFrom`, the token owner has to first call the `approve` function to approve the transfer.

You're saying that "transferFrom includes also the approval by the owner", but unless you have overwritten the function, it doesn't do approvals - it only uses them. And regardless, you can't approve and trasferFrom in the same contract for one token transfer, since the `msg.sender` would be incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. I don't require you to write down code, but how would I go to solve this?

Comment: You should research how the approve + transferFrom pattern works. If you just want to transfer your tokens to another address, use the simple `transfer` function. But if you want a two-step transfer (you approve someone else to withdraw your tokens + that someone else withdraws them), you need transactions from two different entities